# TYPO3 Hook for preview for multiple languages

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have a TYPO3 installation with multiple languages.
Now I want to create a function that if i.e. a french editor, with french settings, goes to the View (or preview of a page) that he gets the french version and not the default language.

My first idea was to use the `PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface` and then change the URL for the right language

in ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']['tx_editordashboard'] =
    \Vendor\Editordashboard\Hooks\Backend\CheckUserCountry::class;
```

in my CheckUserCountry.php class

```
<?php

namespace TRUMPF\Editordashboard\Hooks\Backend;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView;

class CheckUserCountry implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{


/**
 * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element.
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling 
 parent object
 * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default 
functionalities
 * @param string $headerContent Header content
 * @param string $itemContent Item content
 * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
 */
public function preProcess(PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, 
&$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row) {echo "bam";}
}
```

But the Hook doesn't work if I click on the "View" Button. Any ideas so solve the problem?